# How to debug something in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: debugging, svn, tortoisesvn

We currently face a strange problem on one desk that TortoiseSVN allows ot open "Show log", but closes that without any action by the user. To help solving that question, I would like to "Debug" TortoiseSVN.

Is there an easy way to debug TortoiseSVN? Here are some of the requirements:

- Allow to write a debug log file
- Control where that file is written
- If possible, tailor what should be written

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable the debug output via the settings dialog:
`Settings dialog -> Advanced -> DebugOutputString` (set to true)

After that, use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to log all the debug output messages.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Only works for GUI part of Tortoise, and didn't help to resolve my issue, but anyways was very helpful to learn about such debugging method.