# Tortoise SVN transfer at 0 byte/s

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Tortoise SVN 1.8.10 on a Windows 7 machine, connecting to the server on a linux machine.

Until about two weeks ago everything was working fine, but suddenly SVN stopped working. Whatever action I try on the project (update, logs, commit, etc) the transfer proceeds at 0 byte/s and eventually times out.

I am connecting through a VPN and that seems to work fine, as I can SSH login in the linux server and transfer files from there. I can browse the SVN repository trough Firefox.

I tried different connections, I updated Tortoise, used https and nothing worked. I'm not using a proxy and I don't need a proxy.

In the office they said they didn't change any settings, I have another colleague using SVN and it works for him.

How can I investigate this issue? Can I have SVN display some logs for example or to monitor the traffic from my machine to the server?

**EDIT**
in the end updating the VPN client solved the issue, please feel free to close the post and thanks to everyone for the help

Comment: Try command-line client.

Comment: Hi I tried the command line client too of Tortoise and it just hangs there on an svn update command. Eventually it display a E175012 connection timed out error

Comment: In such case you should check the vpn / proxy stuff. Since your web browser is able to connect, I'd compare settings in SVN client and in web browser.

Comment: Can you ping the server? If this is an `http://` connection, can you pull up the URL in a browser?

Comment: ping is disabled on the server but I can SSH into it and even transfer files with WinSCP. I can use the SVN url in the browser and see the repository or download files from there

Comment: so what the hell is the answer to this ridiculous problem????

Comment: The company I work for had installed an automatic update of our VPN server and apparently no one knew it. Updating the client solved it. But I never found out the cause, on a different connection it worked fine even with the old client. Mistery

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20637753/1023562

*Enable the debug output via the settings dialog: Settings dialog -> Advanced -> DebugOutputString (set to true)
After that, use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to log all the debug output messages.*

The autor of the answer is the autor of the TorotoiseSVN, I thnk.

Comment: It won't help since the debug log relates to TortoiseSVN internals (e.g. showing dialogs) and is specific to TortoiseSVN only. I guess that @malavock can reproduce the same issue using a command-line client, so the troubleshooting path has to be different: check connectivity to the server. BTW, you are right Stefan is TortoiseSVN's developer.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to TortoiseSVN version 1.9.3 the issue was resolved

Unlike your issue, my issue was because I'm transferring large file (about 150MB) using slow internet connection